# How to extract the before-last column of a table with selenium webdriver on Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, extract

Hello I am trying to extract all data from the column named "Nb B" at this webpage :
https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php

I used this line of code currently:

```
    nb_bookies = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 
   10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@id and 
   @role=\"row\"]/td[last()]")))]
```

The problem is that a new column has been added to the table so that 'Nb B' is now the before-last column of the table. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
td[last()]
```

with

```
td[last() - 1]
```

or

```
td[not(i)][last()]
```